# GeoServer clustering kahadb issue

Tags: geoserver

I set up GeoServer cluster with ebmedded JMS-brokers (basically as described here -  https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/clustering/clustering/active/index.html) in Multiple Masters - Multiple Slaves mode. Until yesterday everithing worked fine (~1 month). 
But then we get just stuck in any changes made to catalog. Log was hanging on

```
Creating an instance of: class org.geoserver.cluster.impl.handlers.catalog.JMSCatalogModifyEventHandlerSPI
```

In my setup all configuration changes sending to just one (primary) GeoServer instance, based on haproxy load balancing. 
I spent some time and found that GeoServer embedded broker database (kahadb) grew to 1Gb on this problem instance, and that default setting for disk usage in GeoServer config for it is exactly 1Gb - 
`activemq.broker.systemUsage.storeUsage=1 gb`. Deleting kanadb and restarting problematic instance did the trick - it works again.

And now the question - should each GeoServer instance have own copy of kahadb? Or should it be the same kahadb for each instance?

If each GeoServer instance should have own kahadb, why log-files is not truncated? ActiveMQ documentation says, by default they will be cleared every 30s, but seems it is not working properly. More strange - except this kahadb disk space issue, cluster works just fine, replicating all the changes to each node.